# Wrap for multiple items js

Tags: javascript, foreach, appendchild

Еhere is a script that makes a wrapper for one slide.
How correctly to make, what in a wrap would get three slides?

```
let wrappedSlides = Array.from(container.children).map(slide => {
            let slideWrap = document.createElement('div');
            slideWrap.classList.add('slides-flow__slide');
            slideWrap.appendChild(slide);
            return slideWrap;
        });
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible plus it looks like you're simply too lazy to google for a solution yourself.

Comment: `makes a wrapper`, what do you call a wrapper? What's a slide? I can't understand your problem/question

Comment: wrapper  - `slideWrap`, slide - element of array

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
static createMarkup(container, transition = false) {

        let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.classList.add('slides-flow__wrap');
        if (transition) wrapper.style.transition = `transform ${transition}`;

        const slides = Array.from(container.children);
        let appendSlides = [];
        while(slides.length > 0) {
            appendSlides.push(slides.splice(0,3))
        }
        let wrappedSlides = appendSlides.map(slide => {
            let slideWrap = document.createElement('div');
            slideWrap.classList.add('slides-flow__slide');
            slide.forEach(el => slideWrap.appendChild(el));
            return slideWrap;
        });

        wrappedSlides.forEach(wrappedSlide => {
            wrapper.appendChild(wrappedSlide);
        });


        container.appendChild(wrapper);

        return {
            container,
            wrapper,
            slides: wrappedSlides
        }
    }
```